# Retrofit query parameters adding apiKey

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I'm using Kotlin to develop a news source app.

```
public interface NewsAPI {

    @GET("v2/top-headlines")
        fun getTooNews(
            @Query("my_apiKey") String "apiKey");
            )
    }
```

Is this the correct way to add the `apiKey` via query parameters?

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Yes this is the way except you have an extra ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.Use apiKey:String instead of String "apiKey".:)

Comment: This does give a warning, redundant use of semicolon.

Comment: Yes,Kotlin doesnt use semicolon unlike java.